# If liquids absorb heat from their surroundings to become gas, why does gas feel hotter than liquid?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, temperature

I know what you're thinking, "OP, are you for real!? Gas is obviously hotter because it absorbed heat from the environment!"

But hear me out. Yes it is hotter in absolute terms because it absorbed heat to become that way and if you placed one thermometer in the liquid and one in the gas then you'll get a higher temperature reading from the gas.

However, when you read the question again it says "absorbs heat from its environment" thus heat is removed from the environment, thus the environment is less hot than before, and if that "environment" was the palm of our hand (and it was heavier than air so it didn't fly off) then that gas should feel cooler than the liquid because it absorbed heat from our skin thus the nerve endings in our skin had temperature removed from them and now give us the sensation of being cooled down. (assume that the boiling point of the substance is our body temperature).

Comment: You need to revise some of your very basic premises, namely that the things always get hotter when you apply heat to them. That's not always so.

Comment: Be aware that being hot, or comparatively hotter and colder, depends on multiple objective parameters and is also a subjective, physiological and psychological parameter. Not only temperature plays role, but also heat capacity, specific and volumetric heat capacity, heat conductivity, at vapors also latent heat of evaporation, state of the human body surface tissues, state of the mind. An aluminium block and a piece of styrofoam, both heated up to 80 deg C, would be perceived very differently. So does 100 deg C water and water vapour.

Comment: Ok I think this will go way over my head. I'm only asking this to better understand refrigerants in HVAC, but I guess this is more than I need to know for that job!

Comment: If there is gaseous and liquid phase of the same matter, the gas is able to release energy of latent heat of evaporation. still staying at the boiling temperature. That is the reason why burns by water vapor are worse than due boiling water. As 1 g of vapor releases due its condentation to boiling water 5.5 tims more energy than is needed to warm up 1 g of water from 0 to 100 deg C.